# How to avoid default_value in field with ArcPy cursor (e.g. row[i]=None)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cursor, null, default-value

Some field in field_list has default_value=1
After executing the following code, such field is filled with the value «1», but normal fields are filled «Null». How could I avoid this for the field (default_value=1) and write there «Null»?

```
with a.da.UpdateCursor(table, field_list, where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            if row[i] == 0:
                row[i] = None
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Your code assigns NULL values where *zeros* are present, not ones. Of course, if the dataset is a shapefile, it doesn't support NULLs.

Comment: Only mdb and gdb. Field with assigned default value = 1. I want Null, but the script set default value, unfortunatelly

Comment: You want to replace 1 with None? Try `row = [None if val==1 else val for val in row]`

Comment: No, I write `row = None` but as a result there are "1" in cells not "Null". It's because default value for the field =1

Answer (score 0):

The answer, at least with ArcPy Data Access cursors, is that you cannot avoid the behavior you are seeing because of a known defect with ArcPy Data Access cursors.  From [BUG-000091314: When using the data access module and an update curs..](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA5MTMxNA==):

> ## Bug BUG-000091314
>
> ### Synopsis
>
> When using the data access module and an update cursor, row values
> cannot be updated to null.
>
> ### Alternate Solution
>
> Use the old update cursor or use the Calculate Field geoprocessing tool.

This defect was logged in 2015, which means it was logged right after Pro 1.0 was released, and the defect still exists today in Pro 2.9.x, so I would not be holding your breath for a resolution any time soon.

### **UPDATE**

Esri finally addressed this defect in Pro 3.1 through the introduction of a new `explicit` parameter in the ArcPy DA [InsertCursor - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) and [UpdateCursor - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).

Modifying the OP's code using the new parameter to force nullable fields to accept NULL:

```py
with a.da.UpdateCursor(table, field_list, where_clause, explicit=True) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            if row[i] == 0:
                row[i] = None
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```